# How files with extension o.d generating

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

After executing command "make" in ubuntu 15.04 I found files .*.o.d with content like this:

```
objdir.o: objdir.cpp /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/assert.h /usr/include/features.h \
 /usr/include/bits/predefs.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h ../include/ntstatus.h ../include/windef.h \
 ../include/winnt.h ../include/basetsd.h /usr/include/ctype.h \
 /usr/include/bits/types.h /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/endian.h /usr/include/bits/endian.h \
 /usr/include/bits/byteswap.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/stddef.h /usr/include/string.h \
 /usr/include/bits/string3.h ../include/pshpack2.h ../include/poppack.h \
 ../include/pshpack4.h ../include/guiddef.h ../include/pshpack8.h \
 ../include/winternl.h debug.h object.h list.h unicode.h objdir.h \
 object.inl ntcall.h thread.h timer.h fiber.h token.h mem.h \
 /usr/include/unistd.h /usr/include/bits/posix_opt.h \
 /usr/include/bits/environments.h /usr/include/bits/confname.h \
 /usr/include/getopt.h /usr/include/bits/unistd.h process.h symlink.h
```

but in those files I got wrong paths - for example instead of /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3 there must be /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
So how those files generating and how I can change paths in those files?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate dependency files (`.d`) using `gcc -MM` in gnu environment. From [this page](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html):

> The solution is fairly simple: every time we build a .o file, we also
>   create a file with extension .d (for dependency) that records **which
>   files were used to create the corresponding .o file**. (Note that we do
>   not create the .d files ahead of time, in contrast to some
>   approaches.) The .d files will be written in the make language itself,
>   and included into the primary Makefile. We can generate the files
>   using the **-MM option of gcc**